# Stripe Integration in Nodejs, Need to transfer form data and add other payment options

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe-payment-intent, stripe-payments-js

Trying to Integrate Stripe Payment Gateway in Donation Webpage.
Have least knowledge in integrating payment gateways

After following a simple tutorial, am able to complete payment but cant add other payment options as well as transfer User data in frontend as well Backend.

sepa_debit and wallets are not visible.

Not able to display the amount the user enters in the form in the payment of stripe

Home.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Stripe Payment Demo</title>
<body>
    <h3>Welcome to Payment Gateway</h3>
    
    <form action="payment" method="POST" >
        <input type="number" id="amount">
    <input type="submit">
    <script
        src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
        class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<%= key %>"
        data-amount=document.getElementById(amount)
        data-currency="inr"
        data-name="Sparks Foundation NGO"
        data-description="Donate Now to Better Somesone's Life"
        data-locale="auto" >
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

var Publishable_Key = 'pk_test_51MY8LgSIjyhEAXRbDHDLZUfwFVuxKzUWesWXwQLfnb6vOoAyvelN0KVUGSwXdlez6FhoLgWD6Ngn4DKa6eZnG2c400Dn74v3r2'
var Secret_Key = 'sk_test_51MY8LgSIjyhEAXRbqRP5AWJWYbdXJ0Tj9P1FoYM83U6j0ckHItUTCw8PfAeBKPpP4PJHQ5kzqexK1q6xgsFhxVTB00H7MQtYig'

const stripe = require('stripe')(Secret_Key)

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(bodyparser.json())

// View Engine Setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('Home', {
    key: Publishable_Key
    })
})

app.post('/payment', function(req, res){

    // Moreover you can take more details from user
    // like Address, Name, etc from form
    stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.stripeEmail,
        source: req.body.stripeToken,
        name: 'Gourav Hammad',
        address: {
            line1: 'TC 9/4 Old MES colony',
            postal_code: '452331',
            city: 'Indore',
            state: 'Madhya Pradesh',
            country: 'India',
        }
    })
    
    .then((customer) => {

       return charge = async()=>{
        await stripe.PaymentIntent.create({
            payment_method_types: ["card","sepa_debit","wallets"],
            amount: 1099,
            currency: 'usd',
        });
    }
        
    })
    .then((charge) => {
        res.send("Success") // If no error occurs
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.send(err)   
        console.log(err); // If some error occurs
    });
})

app.listen(port, function(error){
    if(error) throw error
    console.log("Server created Successfully")
})
```

Reference Image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFcqP.png)

Please help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You've revealed your secret key in your post and I'd recommend you to [roll](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#rolling-keys) your key as soon as possible.

You are still using the legacy Stripe Checkout and it doesn't support sepa_debit nor wallet. You should [migrate](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration) to the new Stripe Checkout so that your customers can have more payment method options including wallets (Apple Pay/Google Pay).

Lastly, `wallets` is not a valid value for [payment_method_types](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method_types), you should just use `card` if you want to provide Apple Pay or Google Pay to your customers.